# How to Implement ajax pagination in bootstrap modal with kaminari gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using kaminari gem in my ROR project to show the records in pages with bootstrap model box.

I want the next page to be loaded without reloading the whole page using ajax.

I found some examples on the net but they don't work for me.

How to do this?

Comment: HI, Please show what you have already tried. So, others don't waste time there. Have a look at this guide - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you read the kaminari docs you will find your answer. https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#ajax-links-crazy-simple-but-works-perfectly